# Are there any API that allow to retrieve the musicians involved in a certain album/track?

Tags: api, spotify, deezer, musicbrainz, discogs-api

I've looked at MusicBrainz, Deezer, Discogs, and Spotify API and none of them provide a direct relationship between an album/track and the musicians who played it. Usually, for example, you can get that Queen created the album "*Made in Heaven*", but you can't get the members (Mercury, May, etc) of Queen who played/composed it at that time. [It seems something provided by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Made_in_Heaven#Personnel), but not always easy to scrape since the pages don't always have the same template.
Any ideas how to solve this issue? Thanks!